# What storage engine does TFS2010 use?

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

Does TFS2010 still use the VSS storage engine for source control?

Comment: TTFS has _nothing_ to do with VSS, and never had.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server):

Team Foundation source control stores all code, as well as a record of all changes and current check-outs in a SQL Server database.

Comment: if I wanted to query those tables, what are they?